# Complex SOAP Request

Tags: android, soap, ksoap2, ksoap, android-ksoap2

My request is as below...

```
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <Search>
         <specialties>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <arr:int>1</arr:int>
            <arr:int>2</arr:int>
            <arr:int>3</arr:int>
         </specialties>                      
         <gender>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <arr:string>male</arr:string>
            <arr:string>female</arr:string>
         </gender>            
      </Search>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

How to pass the same with Android Soap Request...

Thanks.

Comment: Use `SoapObject.addProperty.("name of object",value (may be string or array of String))` in ksoap2.

Comment: tried the same.. not working !!!

Answer (score 1):

try in this way it will help u

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        SoapObject Search= new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "Search");
        for(int i=0;i<mID.length & i<qty.length;i++){
            SoapObject Specialities=  new SoapObject("http://www.FoodTruck.zsl.com/", "Specialities");
            Specialities.addProperty("MenuItemID", mID[i]);
            Specialities.addProperty("Quantity",1);
            Specialities.addProperty("CartItems", CartItems);
        }
        request.addProperty("Search", Search);
```

Answer (score 0):

I passed complete xml as byte array to Output stream instead of converting SOAP envelope and it worked !!!